# Flutter loop carousel cards

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, carousel

I have a problem with flutter. I wanted to create a carousel that's in loop, so when you are at the final element, the first one is the next. But without using a 3rd party widget.

Is there any way that you could create a characteristic like this with just pure dart?

Here is what I could do:

```
class TemplatesBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TemplatesBodyState createState() => _TemplatesBodyState();
}

class _TemplatesBodyState extends State<TemplatesBody> {
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 12),
        child: Column(

          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
            Text(
              'Templates for restaurants',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.8)),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30.0,),
            SizedBox(
              height: 380, 
              child: PageView.builder(
                itemCount: 5,
                controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.7),
                onPageChanged: (int index) => setState(() => _index = index),
                itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                  return Transform.scale(
                    scale: i == _index ? 1 : 0.9,
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 9,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Template ${i + 1}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 32,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.brown.withOpacity(.5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you not want to use a package ? [flutter_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper) is great imo.

Comment: I wanted to learn more by doing it myself, rather than just use an existent widget.

Comment: Check the packages GitHub source if you want to learn how they did it

Answer (score 0):

I have used this flutter carousal package and it is working fine.
https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider/install

And My full source code is attached below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

final List<Map<String, String>> carousalCards = [
  {"cardName": "Rohini"},
  {"cardName": "Babu"},
  {"cardName": "Hari"}
];

class CarousalCards extends StatelessWidget {
  const CarousalCards({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          title: const Center(
            child: Text("Carousal Cards",
                style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(41, 82, 119, 1))),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: CarouselSlider.builder(
          itemCount: carousalCards.length,
          options: CarouselOptions(height: 950),
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index, realIdx) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 0),
              child: Column(children: [
                Container(
                    width: 420,
                    height: 120,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xFF1f4068),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      carousalCards[index]['cardName'].toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                    )))
              ]),
            );
          },
        )));
  }
}
```

in pubspec.yaml add the dependency,

```
dependencies:
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
```